# Increasing space between text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I am making a picture in tikz, and I have some labels that don't look nice. Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\definecolor{zut}{RGB}{253,200,0}
\definecolor{nar}{RGB}{240,95,0}
\definecolor{pla}{RGB}{134,206,255}

\begin{document}
\center



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[zut, fill=pla, thick] (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 2cm);
    \draw[nar, fill=white, thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw[zut, dashed, thick] (0,0) ellipse (1.4cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw[nar, dashed, thick] (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 0.5cm);
    \draw[dotted, thick] (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 0.15cm);
    \draw[-latex'] (0,0) to (0,3.5);
    \node at (-0.2,3.5) {$z$};
    \draw[-latex'] (0,0) to (5,0);
    \node at (5.2,0.2) {$y$};
    \draw[-latex'] (0,0) to (-2.5,-2.5);
    \node at (-2.2,-2.7) {$x$}; 
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) to (0,-3);
    \draw[latex-, thick] (1.8,1) -- (3,1.7) --(6.8,1.7);
    \node[align=center] at (4.7,2.2) {\textsf{Vanjski horizont događaja}\\
    $r=r_+=M+\sqrt{M^2-a^2}$};
    \draw[->] (-0.4,3) to [bend right=80] (0.4,3.1);
    \node at (-0.6,3) {$\phi$};
    \node at (0.6,2.4) {$\theta=0$};
    \node at (0.8,-2.4) {$\theta=\pi$};
    \draw[->, red, dashed] (-5,2) to [bend left=10] (-3.8,1);
    \node at (-5,2.3) {ergosfera};
    \draw[->, red, dashed] (-4.2,-2.2) to [bend right=30] (-1.8,-1);
    \node[align=center] at (-5,-2.4) {horizont \\ događaja};
    \draw[->, red, dashed] (5.5,0.5) to [bend left=10] (4,-0.35); 
    \node[align=center] at (6,0.85) {$r=M+\sqrt{M^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}$};
    \draw[->, red, dashed] (5,-1.5) to [bend left=20] (3,-0.35);
    \node[align=center] at (6,-1.5) {ergoregija};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here's the picture

[image]

The 'Vanjski horizont događaja' is a bit too close to the formula beneath it. I tried adding `\vspace` but that didn't do a thing. The longer solution is just dividing those two and manually setting the nodes, but I'm sure there's a way to fix this without separating anything, I'm just not that good at tikz :D

Comment: Try `\\[.5ex]` on the line break between the Vanjski line and the formula.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oops, didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for any TikZ tricks:

```
\node[align=center] at (4.7,2.3) {\textsf{Vanjski horizont događaja}\\[10pt]
$r=r_+=M+\sqrt{M^2-a^2}$};
```

The syntax `\\[<length]` is defined by LaTeX. It starts a new line and adds `<length>` of vertical space before the next line.

Comment: Wohoo :D Works, didn't know of that one :D Thanks ^^